# ZStack with RoundedRectangles as bar chart. How to fill properly?

Tags: swift, charts, swiftui

I want to create a vertical bar chart using two RoundedRectangles in a ZStack (Slider for demo purpose):

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {

    @State var value : CGFloat = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).foregroundColor(Color.gray).frame(width: 300, height: 30)
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).foregroundColor(Color.green).frame(width: value, height: 30)
            }
            Text(Int(value).description)
            Slider(value: $value, in: 0...300).frame(width: 300)
        }
    }
}
```

This works well for all values above ~30. Values below render the green rectangle to small to show it right over the first rectangle because of the corner radius:

[image]

How can i prevent this or how can i create this simple bar chart an other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need clipped shape as below

[image: demo]

```
ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).foregroundColor(Color.gray).frame(width: 300, height: 30)
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).foregroundColor(Color.green).frame(width: value, height: 30)
}
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))   // << here !!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution using `mask` and `overlay`:

```
struct Chart: View {
    @Binding var value: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        let rectangle = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        return rectangle.overlay(
            GeometryReader { _ in
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: value)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
            }
            .mask(rectangle)
        )
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
    }
}
```

```
Chart(value: $value)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 30)
```